# Best way to search for Wolfram Language documentation and answers?

Tags: searching

I just found this custom Google search engine I made 8 years ago to search through Wolfram Language Documentation, Mathematica StackExchange, MathGroup, and Wolfram Community. I was surprised to find that this was still producing better results than the built-in search inside the official documentation or a regular Google Search. Maybe others here would find it useful as well.

https://tiny.cc/wolfram 
or 
https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=014972067149191458711:ebnc0fyumfu

I've also found Perplexity AI search to be quite good.

What tools do people here use to find exactly what they need when coding in WL?

Comment: **What tools do people here use to find exactly what they need when coding in WL?** I also search for Mathematica commands using  something called `google` :)  Once I find the command I need, then use Mathematica help to look it for more details.  Version 14 has more AI built-in, so may be this can be used. But I have not tried it.